# How can I generate random (int) values with specific size and mean?

Tags: python, numpy, random

I need to generate  1000 samples (int) with average 2.
Do you think such a function already exists in python?

Comment: What does prevent you from writing one?

Comment: @Cargo23 this is a python question and that's a matlab one

Comment: There are many different distribution that could fit this requirement. This is too vague

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NumPy's [`random.randint(low, high=None, size=None, dtype=int)`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.randint.html) generates "random integers from the “discrete uniform” distribution of the specified dtype in the “half-open” interval [`low`, `high`)".

Therefore, to generate random integers with mean of 2 just make sure that the interval you specify is centred on 2.

```py
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.random.randint(0,5,10000000).mean()
1.999827
>>> np.random.randint(-10,15,10000000).mean()
2.000426
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want to stick to the standard library, you can use the random libary

```
import random
import statistics

example = [random.randint(0, 4) for _ in range(1000)]
print(statistics.mean(example))
```

I arbitrarily selected 0 and 4 for the range passed to randint.  You can select other ranges so long as they are centered on 2.